# Let $r_0,r_1,...,r_m$ be the real roots of $a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_0$.Is there a closed-form expression for $\sum_{i=1}^mr_i -\sum_{i=1}^m1/r_i$?

Tags: polynomials, roots

> Let $r_0, r_1, ... ,r_m$ be the real roots of $a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_0$, with $a_0\ne0.$ Is there a closed-form expression for $$ \ \ \ \ \ \sum_{i=1}^mr_i - \sum_{i=1}^m \frac{1}{r_i} \ \ \ \ ?$$

Comment: Did you intend to restrict to real roots only?

Comment: @copper.hat Yes.

Comment: The algebra-precalculus tag made me wonder... Out of my depth...

Comment: @copper.hat So it is harder considering only the real ones?

Comment: Harder for me :-). I don't know any trick for separating out the real roots...

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you anyway, wait for an answer and you'll know too. :D

Comment: What happens if one of the roots is $0$? Or do you assume $a_0\neq 0$?

Comment: @KimFierens Sorry for that, just edited.

Comment: It is much much much harder considering only the real roots (to know if a root is real you basically need to know all the roots explicitly). If you consider all roots then its fairly simple.

Comment: Take $n=2$ as an example. Then $S=-\frac{a_1}{a_2} + \frac{a_1}{a_0}$ if $a_1^2 - 4a_0a_2 \geq 0$ and $S=0$ otherwise (no real roots). The general $n$ case will have many more such sub-cases.

Comment: @Winther I see you have added one "much", ahahahah! I agree it deserves all those "much". Could one write a paper on it?

Comment: I don't know. Is there somewhere sums like this pops up so that it is interesting to know them?

Comment: @Winther No idea. I asked my question because there was the same specific request in a time trial (all the roots of that polynomial were real, though).

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{i=1}^mr_i=-\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}$. Now substitute $\frac{1}{x}$ for $x$ then $\sum_{i=1}^m \frac{1}{r_i}=-\frac{a_{1}}{a_0}$.

Comment: The question is about real roots

Comment: Out of curiosity, since I might be missing something about polynomials in $\mathbb{C}$, how is that always true if we consider the complex roots too? Perhaps it's trivial but I'd be grateful if you could explain me.

Comment: Because $a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\ldots+a_0 = a_n(x-r_1)(x-r_2)\ldots(x-r_n) = a_n x^n -a_n(r_1+r_2+\ldots + r_n)x^{n-1} + \ldots + a_n(-1)^nr_1r_2\ldots r_n $. It is only true if we consider *all* roots.

Comment: @Winther I see, thanks.